# After making a selection float in GIMP, how to move it in a straight vertical or horizontal direction?

Tags: gimp, layers

I am doing kerning manually in GIMP, i.e. trying to move letters closer to each other, but my hand movements are not exact enough on my mouse so whenever I move a layer to the left or right, it also goes a little in the vertical direction. I wonder if there is some feature that enables me to move a layer left or right (alternatively only up and down) so that I don't accidentally sway it a little down or a little up. Does anyone know? I am a beginner when it comes to GIMP.

Comment: If you are typing the text in GIMP itself, I hope you found the control to change the kerning while typing the text, in the text tool options dialog?

Comment: @jsbueno Oh yeah I've seen that but it doesn't always work that well.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It's very simple:

1. Select `move tool`
2. `Select the layer` (or the float selection) to be moved
3. `Click on the layer` (or the float selection) to be moved
4. Move the layer using the `keyboard cursor keys`

Comment: I had no idea, this method even works in MS Paint. Thanks.

Comment: Is there a shortcut to move the layer faster with the cursor keys?  I have a large image and it seems that the cursor keys are best for pixel-perfect alignment adjustments and not for moving a layer several hundred pixels.

Comment: As told in jsbueno answer, hold down the **shift key** while moving.

Answer (score 10):

You can use the arrow keys with the move tool as in Paolo's answer - note that if you hold shift as you press the arrow keys, the movement is made in larger
steps instead of one pixel at a time.

Another way of doing it is select the move tool, start moving your layer in the direction wanted and press and hold the `CTRL` key: movements in the other direction (i.e. horizontal if you started moving it on the vertical) will only happen after a large threshold in that direction - so it becomes easy to move only in one direction.

Still another option is to use image guides (click on the rulers on the sides and drag horizontal or vertical guides onto your image), position the guide along the top or bottom border of the layer you are moving, then make sure  `View->Snap to Guides`is enabled , and move the layer - it will be easy to keep on track.

Comment: `Command` key on macOS, it seems.